# VB.Net unexpected addition in a loop?

Tags: vb.net

The program is supposed to get the value that the user has input into `textbox1` (goal level) and use it for calculations for the variable `exp`, and then output the final result into `label3`.
However, the result comes out wrong.

Here is the exp system:

```
Each lvl require 2 exp more than the previous lvl.
lvl1-2 = 1 exp (1 exp)
lvl2-3 = 3 exp (4 exp)
lvl3-4 = 5 exp (9 exp)
lvl4-5 = 7 exp (14 exp)
lvl5-6 = 9 exp (23 exp)
```

So the formula is: `(2*n) - 3` (exp required from level n-1 to n)

Then the loop is used to sum all of the exp required, to give you the total exp required from 0exp to the goal level.

Here is what the program outputs when I input the numbers:

1 = `0`

2 = `1`

3 = `6`

4 = `15`

5 = `28`

Here is what the expected/correct output should be:

1 = `0`

2 = `1`

3 = `4`

4 = `9`

5 = `14`

Here is the actual program:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim exp As Integer = 0

    Label3.Text = ""

    If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
        x = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)

        For i As Integer = 2 To x
            exp += (2 * x) - 3
        Next

        Label3.Text = exp.ToString
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your table is wrong. To get to lvl 5 you need `16` (1+3+5+7), not `14`, and to get to lvl 6 you need `25` (1+3+5+7+9), not `23`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim x As Integer
Dim exp As Integer = 0

Label3.Text = ""

If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    x = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)

    For i As Integer = 2 To x
        exp += (2 * i) - 3     '<- ERROR HERE
    Next

    Label3.Text = exp.ToString
End If

End Sub
```

You were always adding the level 5 xp, not the xp of the current level.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim x As Integer
Dim exp As Integer = 0

Label3.Text = ""

If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    x = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)

    For i As Integer = 2 To x
        exp += (2 * i) - 3
    Next

    Label3.Text = exp.ToString
End If
End Sub
```